# How to find time on site using gapi?

Tags: google-analytics-api

How to find `Time on Site` using google API ( gapi). I am not sure what dimension I should be using with `Time on Site` metrics.

Comment: Just check the following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591901/how-to-determine-time-on-site-in-javascript

Comment: The above link does not talk about how to use GAPI to get Time on Site. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have a dimension with it but there are any number of them that you could use. For example:

- Visitor Type (New and Returning)
- Languages
- Continents
- Campaigns
- Keywords
- Operating system
- isMobile
- and on and on.

It depends on what dimension you want to see `time on site` shown against.

See [How Metrics are Calculated](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsDataCalculation.html#howMetricsAreCalculated). It touches on uses of `time on site`.

Comment: Does it make sense to use Browsers as Dimension and then loop over the array to get time on site system wide as data for browsers is mutually exclusive.

Comment: @user395881 I suppose you could. I tried it out in the [Data Feed Query Explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html) and it looked possible to do just that.

Comment: In GAPI ( Google API ), I don't understand how to send empty dimensions. For e.g.

$ga->requestReportData(__ID___,null,array('visitors','visits','pageviews'),array('-visitors' ...

I cannot send null, '' in dimensions parameter so I see myself being forced to use some dimension.

Comment: @user395881 Have you tried `$ga->requestReportData(ID_,,array('visitors','visits','pageviews')`

Comment: @user395881 See http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/issues/detail?id=15